# How to add Phone no field in enquiry form of woocommerce product page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added Quick enquiry form to woocommerce product page. but it contains only Name,Email, subject & enquiry option.

Take a look here http://demo.hashkart.com

I want to add exta field called phone no. in this form

Please suggest me solution for this or any extra plugins.

Comment: Can you show some coding related to this ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I am using product-enquiry-for-woocommerce plugin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE :** Take back up before implementing this.

Go to `wp-content > plugins > product-enquiry-for-woocommerce > data >contact.php`

And **replace** content of `contact.php` with following code :

```
    <?php
    /* SimpleModal Contact Form
     * http://simplemodal.com/
     * http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/
     *
     * Copyright (c) 2012 Eric Martin - http://ericmmartin.com
     *
     * Licensed under the MIT license:
     *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
     *
     * Revision: $Id: contact-dist.php 269 2011-12-17 23:24:14Z emartin24 $
     *
     */

    //date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    global $to;
    if(isset($_POST['wdm_form_dataset']))
    {
        $form_data = $_POST['wdm_form_dataset'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['wdm_admin_email']))
    {
        $to_adm = $_POST['wdm_admin_email'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['wdm_site_name']))
    {
        $site_name = $_POST['wdm_site_name'];
    }

    // User settings
    if (!empty($form_data['user_email']))
        $to = $form_data['user_email'];
    else if(isset($to_adm))
        $to = $to_adm;

    if (!empty($form_data['default_sub']))
        $subject = $form_data['default_sub'];
    else if(isset($site_name))
        $subject = "Enquiry for a product from ".$site_name;


     //Include extra form fields and/or submitter data?
     //false = do not include

    $extra = array(
        "form_subject"  => true,
        "your_number" =>true,
        "form_cc"   => (isset($form_data['enable_send_mail_copy']) ? true : false),
        "ip"        => false,
        "user_agent"    => false
    );

    // Process
    $action = isset($_POST["action"]) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
    if (empty($action)) {
        // Send back the contact form HTML
        $output = "<div style='display:none'>
        <div class='contact-top'></div>
        <div class='contact-content'>
            <h1 class='contact-title'>Product Enquiry:</h1>
            <div class='contact-loading' style='display:none'></div>
            <div class='contact-message' style='display:none'></div>
            <form action='#' style='display:none'>

                <input type='text' id='wdm_product_name' class='contact-input' name='wdm_product_name' value='' readonly=true />
                <label for='contact-name'>*Name:</label>
                <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' />
                <label for='contact-email'>*Email:</label>
                <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='email' tabindex='1002' />";

        if ($extra["form_subject"] && $extra["your_number"]) {
            $output .= "
                <label for='contact-subject'>Subject:</label>
                <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='subject' value='' tabindex='1003' />";
            $output .= "
                <label for='contact-phone'>Phone Number:</label>
                <input type='text' id='contact-phone' class='contact-input' name='phone' value='' tabindex='1007' />";
        }

        $output .= "<input type='hidden' id='wdm_product_url' class='contact-input' name='wdm_product_url' value='' />";

        $output .= "<input type='hidden' id='wdm_form_mail_to' class='contact-input' name='wdm_form_mail_to' value='' />";

        $output .= "<input type='hidden' id='wdm_form_def_sub' class='contact-input' name='wdm_form_def_sub' value='' />";

        $output .= "<input type='hidden' id='wdm_website_name' class='contact-input' name='wdm_website_name' value='' />";

        $output .= "
                <label for='contact-message'>*Enquiry:</label>
                <textarea id='contact-message' class='contact-input' name='message' cols='40' rows='4' tabindex='1004'></textarea>
                <br/>";

        if ($extra["form_cc"]) {
            $output .= "
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input type='checkbox' id='contact-cc' name='cc' value='1' tabindex='1005' /> <span class='contact-cc'>Send me a copy</span>
                <br/>";
        }

        $output .= "
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <button type='submit' class='contact-send contact-button' tabindex='1006'>Send</button>
                <button type='submit' class='contact-cancel contact-button simplemodal-close' tabindex='1007'>Cancel</button>
                <br/>
                <input type='hidden' name='token' value='" . smcf_token($to) . "'/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class='contact-bottom'><a href='http://wisdmlabs.com' target='_blank'>Powered by WisdmLabs</a></div>
    </div>";

     echo $output;

     $to = base64_encode($to);
     $subject = base64_encode($subject);
     $site_name = base64_encode($site_name);

      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                jQuery("#wdm_form_mail_to").val("'.$to.'");
                jQuery("#wdm_form_def_sub").val("'.$subject.'");
                jQuery("#wdm_website_name").val("'.$site_name.'");

            }
            );
     </script>';

    }
    else if ($action == "wdm_send") {
        // Send the email
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);echo "</pre>";exit;
        $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
        $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
        $urphone = isset($_POST["phone"]) ? $_POST["phone"] : "";
        $subject = isset($_POST["wdm_form_def_sub"]) ? $_POST["wdm_form_def_sub"] : "";
        $subject = base64_decode($subject);
        $subject = !empty($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST["subject"] : $subject;
        $product_url = isset($_POST["wdm_product_url"]) ? $_POST["wdm_product_url"] : "";
        $product_name = isset($_POST["wdm_product_name"]) ? $_POST["wdm_product_name"] : "";
        $message = isset($_POST["message"]) ? $_POST["message"] : "";
        $cc = isset($_POST["cc"]) ? $_POST["cc"] : "";
        $token = isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "";
        $to = isset($_POST["wdm_form_mail_to"]) ? $_POST["wdm_form_mail_to"] : "";
        $to = base64_decode($to);
        //echo $to;exit;
        $site_name = isset($_POST["wdm_website_name"]) ? $_POST["wdm_website_name"] : "";
        $site_name = base64_decode($site_name);

        // make sure the token matches
        if ($token === smcf_token($to)) {
            smcf_send($name, $email, $subject, $urphone, $product_url, $product_name, $site_name, $message, $cc);
            echo "Your enquiry sent successfully. We will get back to you soon.";
        }
        else {
            echo "Unfortunately, your enquiry could not be verified.";
        }
    }

    function smcf_token($s) {
        return md5("smcf-" . $s . date("WY"));
    }

    // Validate and send email
    function smcf_send($name, $email, $subject, $urphone, $product_url, $product_name, $site_name, $message, $cc) {
        global $to, $extra;

        // Filter and validate fields
        $name = smcf_filter($name);
        $subject = smcf_filter($subject);
        $email = smcf_filter($email);

        if (!smcf_validate_email($email)) {
            $subject .= " - invalid email";
            $message .= "\n\nBad email: $email";
            $email = $to;
            $cc = 0; // do not CC "sender"
        }

        // Add additional info to the message
        if ($extra["ip"]) {
            $message .= "\n\nIP: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
        if ($extra["user_agent"]) {
            $message .= "\n\nUSER AGENT: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        }

        // Set and wordwrap message body
        $body = "Product Enquiry from <strong>". $site_name . "</strong> <br /><br />";
        $body .= "<strong>Product Name:</strong> '". $product_name ."'<br /><br />";
        $body .= "<strong>Product URL:</strong> ". $product_url ."<br /><br />";
        $body .= "<strong>Customer Name:</strong> ". $name ."<br /><br />";
        $body .= "<strong>Customer Email:</strong> ". $email ."<br /><br />";
        $body .= "<strong>Customer Phone Number:</strong> ". $urphone ."<br /><br />";
        $body .= "<strong>Message:</strong> <br />". $message;
        $body = wordwrap($body, 100);

        // Build header
        $headers = "From: $email\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \n";
        if ($cc == 1) {
            $headers .= "Cc: $email\n";
        }
        // $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/SimpleModalContactForm";

        // UTF-8
        if (function_exists('mb_encode_mimeheader')) {
            $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject, "UTF-8", "B", "\n");
        }
        else {
            // you need to enable mb_encode_mimeheader or risk 
            // getting emails that are not UTF-8 encoded
        }
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";
        //echo "to ".$to."<br>";
        //echo "subject ".$subject."<br>";
        //echo "body ".$body."<br>";
        //echo "headers ".$headers."<br>";exit;
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) or die("Unfortunately, a server issue prevented delivery of your message.");

        //wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) or 
        //  die("Unfortunately, a server issue prevented delivery of your message.");
    }

    // Remove any un-safe values to prevent email injection
    function smcf_filter($value) {
        $pattern = array("/\n/","/\r/","/content-type:/i","/to:/i", "/from:/i", "/cc:/i");
        $value = preg_replace($pattern, "", $value);
        return $value;
    }

    // Validate email address format in case client-side validation "fails"
    function smcf_validate_email($email) {
        $at = strrpos($email, "@");

        // Make sure the at (@) sybmol exists and  
        // it is not the first or last character
        if ($at && ($at < 1 || ($at + 1) == strlen($email)))
            return false;

        // Make sure there aren't multiple periods together
        if (preg_match("/(\.{2,})/", $email))
            return false;

        // Break up the local and domain portions
        $local = substr($email, 0, $at);
        $domain = substr($email, $at + 1);


        // Check lengths
        $locLen = strlen($local);
        $domLen = strlen($domain);
        if ($locLen < 1 || $locLen > 64 || $domLen < 4 || $domLen > 255)
            return false;

        // Make sure local and domain don't start with or end with a period
        if (preg_match("/(^\.|\.$)/", $local) || preg_match("/(^\.|\.$)/", $domain))
            return false;

        // Check for quoted-string addresses
        // Since almost anything is allowed in a quoted-string address,
        // we're just going to let them go through
        if (!preg_match('/^"(.+)"$/', $local)) {
            // It's a dot-string address...check for valid characters
            if (!preg_match('/^[-a-zA-Z0-9!#$%*\/?|^{}`~&\'+=_\.]*$/', $local))
                return false;
        }

        // Make sure domain contains only valid characters and at least one period
        if (!preg_match("/^[-a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/", $domain) || !strpos($domain, "."))
            return false;   

        return true;
    }
    //exit;
    ?>
```

**Reminder:** Plugin providing that feature in `PRO` version.So please use that.I am posting it just for temporary usage and I have not seen its License of usage.

Please let me know either its working or not because its **UNTESTED**.

Comment: it works for me Thank you bro Happy New Year..

Comment: Cheers ! Please accept my answer if it worked for you and you can upvote also :)
Have a nice year !

Comment: @user3867343 Welcome to SO ! If it works for you, then accept the answer so that when other user stuck in similar situation they can decide whether given answer is correct or not.